# Адаптивное меню на Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите как разместить пункт 1 слева,пункты 2,3,4 по центру,а пункт 5 справа так чтобы при смещении экрана ничего не съезжало

например что-то типо этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button id="menu" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll nav-ft pull-left" href="#page-top">пункт 1</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
                <ul class="nav-ft nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#video">пункт 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#news">пункт3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#news">пункт4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#video">пункт 5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#news">пункт6</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Съезжает из-за того, что пункт4 находится вертикально не по центру, а немного выше

Comment: Для центрального блока сделайте так http://zaurmag.ru/priemy-verstki-html-css/kak-vy-rovnyat-gorizontal-noe-menyu-sajta-po-tsentru.html 
А вообще min-width: 1000

Comment: Подскажите как  в данном коде разместить пункты 2,3,4 по центру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте фиксированную ширину сайта или делайте адаптивную верстку.

Либо для `.container` фикс. ширину

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
}
```

Либо при сужении экране меньше `700px` (случайное значение) скрывать либо адаптировать меню

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .navbar .pull-right {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема с размерами шрифтов. Сами позиции пунктов меню маштабируются нормально, просто в текущем размере шрифта у вас надписи уже не влазят.

Вы можете реализовать для каждого варианта размера экрана собственное меню подобрав такой размер шрифта при котором бы помещались все надписи.

Сделать это можно с помощью класов hidden-* и visible-* где * может быть xs,sm,md и т.д. То есть идентификатор вашей ширины, так же как в классах css которыми вы задаете ширину колонок.

например делаем текущий вариант меню видимым только на малых устройствах(visible-sm) и скрываем для остальных (hidden-xs, hidden-md и hidden-lg), а в класе fontSizeSm прописываем размер шрифта для текущей реализации меню.

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <div class="container-fluid fontSizeSm">
        ...
      </div>
    </nav>
```

И так для каждой ширины экрана которая нас не устраивает